# Validating a form to not submit on empty input boxes

Tags: javascript, html, forms

```
// html
<label>Write Data:</label>
</br>
<input type=text id=data name="data"style="width: 14em;"> 
</br> 
</br>
<button id="write" type="submit" formaction="/output4" formmethod="post" style="width: 5em;">Write</button>
<button id="More" type="submit">Add more Parameters</button>

// js
$('#write').click(function(){
  $('#data').each(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == "" || $(this).val() == null) {
      alert("Write Data must be filled out or Remove empty parameter list!");
       return false;
     }
  });
});
```

I have a program where if a user clicks on a button, more write data boxes are appended. I do not want the form to submit unless all the write data boxes are filled out. The snippet above shows the alert box if an input if incomplete but then when you press ok, the form still submits?

Comment: You could listen for `submit` then `preventDefault`.

Comment: don't use multiple `#data` ids

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`.submit()`](https://api.jquery.com/submit/) event handler. Then use either `return false` or `e.preventDefault()` to stop the submit. Also note that `id`'s are unique so `$('#data')` will only be a single element, so the `.each()` isn't needed:

```
$('#formIDHere').submit(function(e){
    if ($('#data').val() == "" || $('#data').val() == null) {
       alert("Write Data must be filled out or Remove empty parameter list!");
       e.preventDefault(); // or `return false`
     }
});
```

---

For many inputs have your input items be a class with the value `class="data"`. Just note you need to to use `e.preventDefault()` using the `e` from the submit event. In this case `return false` is for the `.each()` and not the `submit`. I use it here to stop the `.each` from going so we don't have many unneeded alerts and checks:

```
$('#myForm').submit(function(e){
  $('.data').each(function(){
    if ($(this).val() == "" || $(this).val() == null) {
       alert("Write Data must be filled out or Remove empty parameter list!");
       e.preventDefault(); // This is the preventDefault of submit
       return false; // This stops the .each from continuing 
     }
  });
});
```

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/6b7xo55u/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#write').click(() => {

 // if any one of the inputs is blank canSubmit will end up as false
 // if all are not blank, it will end up as true
  var canSubmit = [...document.querySelectorAll('input')]
    .reduce((acc, input) => acc = input.value === '' ? false : acc , true)

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $("#data").bind("change keyup", function () {      
     if ($("#data").val() != "")
          $(this).closest("form").find(":submit").removeAttr("disabled");
     else
          $(this).closest("form").find(":submit").attr("disabled", "disabled");      
     })
});
</script>
```

This would allow you to disable your submit button until there was data within the input field.